# PHPUnit form with uniqid

Tags: phpunit, sonata

I am testing for the first time PHPUnit. I want to put value into input on form. But the value of the "name" attribut is prefix with **uniqid()**...so I can't find the input field...Here the form:

```
<input type="text" id="s5629e61aaa5fa_titre" name="s5629e61aaa5fa[titre]" required="required" class=" form-control">
```

And this the functionnal test I want:

```
    $form = $crawler->filter('button[type=submit]')
                ->eq(0)
                ->form( array(''));

    var_dump($form);

    $form['titre'] = "Mon titre";
```

Answer (score 1):

For SonataAdmin and symfony functional tests:

```
$form = $crawler->filter('form')->form();
/** @var string $uniqid */
parse_str(parse_url($form->getFormNode()->getAttribute('action'))['query']);
$form["{$uniqid}[name]"]->setValue('Size');
```

Comment: Already deprecated but parse_str(parse_url($form->getFormNode()->getAttribute('action'))['query'],$output); $output['uniqid'] do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Today, I encountered the same challenge. The solution of @rafrsr did work, but didn't not seem like a correct way to do this. An easier way would be to override this uniqid value to something that means something to you. So my solution to add this method to the related SonataAdmin class:

```
public function getUniqId()
{
    return 'my_custom_form_name';
}
```

Now you can just use this name instead of a random value:

```
$form = $crawler->filter('form')->form();
$form["my_custom_form_name[name]"]->setValue('Size');
```